# Docker - configuration file accessible during build time

Tags: docker, ssl, docker-compose, ssl-certificate, dockerfile

I am looking for a solution for the following problem:
our team has the regular 3 stages (local,staging,prod) locally we are using docker-compose , I want to pass a file (.pem) that will be accessible in the Dockerfile so I could run `npm config set cafile`, this is not needed in prod or staging.

this is my Dockerfile

```
FROM node
ARG COMPOSE_MODE
COPY ./package.json ./crt.pem /src/

#if COMPOSE_MODE exsist then set cert
RUN if ! [ "x$COMPOSE_MODE" = "x" ] ; then npm config set cafile /src/crt.pem ; fi
```

However this require me to deliver the crt.pem to every project in every environment. Is their a way to pass a file in docker compose that will be accessible during build time. Or alternatively pass ssl certificate to the local docker demon and it will automatically insert it to /etc/ssl/certs.

Thank you for helping!

Comment: You could have the crt.pem in a docker volume locally and mount it on the container you need it for?

Comment: do you want something like `PEM_PATH=xxx.pem docker-compose build`?

Comment: @jacob.mccrumb thx!
 I tried to mount a volume in docker-compose
  tg-db:
    build:
      context: ../TG_db
      dockerfile: ./scripts/docker/Dockerfile
      args:
        - COMPOSE_MODE="true"
    volumes:
      - ./cert:/etc/ssl/certs/
however it did not work, the volume was accessible only after Dockerfile  finished

Comment: @Siyu thank you for helping. their is no IF COPY in docker therefor it will not help

Comment: @TtheTank I was thinking if you mounted it as a volume you could set the command in dockercompose to `npm config set cafile ... && node app.js` or something like that

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Dockerfile

```
ARG PEM_PATH
COPY $PEM_PATH /src/
```

compose file

```
services:
  node:
    build:
      context: folder
      args:
      - PEM_PATH=${PEM_PATH}
```

Call it with `PEM_PATH=xxx.pem docker-compose build`

Comment: Thank you for Answering, this will not work as the path of the pem will be out of the scope of the COPY, it will only work if the .pem will be in the same repo

Comment: then you have to use volume to mount it at runtime